# How does one communicate their project if they suffer from a learning disability?

Tags: communication, career-development

I aspire to be a researcher one day and hopefully open a bunch of consulting firms to help others.  I have tons of great research project ideas ( e.g. polymer microfluidic circuit design for nano-robotics, etc) but I suffer from mild ADD, so I have a difficult time writing academic like papers, but I can make excellent PowerPoint presentations to communicate my idea, and they are pretty well detailed. I am very specific and I like to present it without elaborating much about it. If I want to be known or be recognised for my contributions, is it necessary for me to write academic papers to communicate my work, or can I simply use another medium of scientific communication such as powerpoint presentation to present my work.

Comment: This seems to be a question about academia, which has it's own Stackexchange site.

Comment: You need to find collaborators who can do the writing.  Which is not at all uncommon in research groups: one person will do the initial draft, others will suggest improvements, someone else will produce the final version.  And someone else might do slides for a conference...

Comment: @jamesqf: Your comment is the most helpful one, even the answers don't do justice. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you aspire to be recognised by academia, you need to use the formal methods. Powerpoint presentations are presentations not serious dissertations. Great for sales people, but without being open to discussion they're not going to be met so well by serious academics I would think. You have to be prepared for peer review and to back up your ideas as well.

If academics are not your target, then yes, PP presentations are great for getting funding and sales, but you usually need some credible academic backing behind them for research funding, over here anyway.

Disclaimer:- I'm not an academic although I deal with plenty of them in a couple of fields.

Answer (score 6):

You are talking about two completely different things - being a researcher and opening a bunch of consulting firms - as if it was one. It's not.

If you want to be a researcher as recognized by academia, then you have to pay your dues, get a PhD from an accredited institution and get three to four research articles published as part of your graduation requirement. Plus a 100-200 page thesis that you will have to defend before a committee comprised of faculty from your department. These academic requirements are non-negotiable.

If you want to open a bunch of consulting firms, then all you need is capital. You can do Powerpoint presentations to your heart's content as part of running your firms - You are operating as a business person and a manager of your firms. No formal degree or formal experience required.

Yes, there are researchers who have opened their own firms. The way they got there was by first earning their credentials. If you want to go that route, you can't escape writing research papers. Powerpoint presentations and youtube videos are not considered to be materials that are fitting for scientific peer review.

Comment: @viethnhiPhuvan Then explain me, how audioslides are now being accepted by some of the  most prominent journals. I have seen an audioslide discussing some design method on journal of microelectronics. I am pretty sure you can pay someone to write a paper for you, like I can do all the work, and make them write it for me. From your profile, you seem like a software engineer, so I have to consult others with the proper credentials. Thanks.

Comment: @NiloyAlam - https://www.elsevier.com/connect/audioslides-allow-authors-to-make-mini-webcasts-about-their-papers You still have to write the paper. Dream on. If you get caught paying somebody to write your papers, that the end of your academic career. Don't take my word for it -  Do you feel lucky?